# Django - Search Query Results Loading Incorrectly

Tags: django, django-models, django-views, django-templates

On my search results page for some reason when a logged in user makes a search query in my gaming application all the results display instead of the query itself.

What needs to get fixed with what I currently have?

I’m building a gaming application where logged in users have access to play different games based on their rank in our application… so when a user makes a search for lets say the letter `d` all the unlocked games and locked games that have the letter `d` should display. I'm currently getting that but the search query shows all results that don't inlcude letter `d`.

This is only happening when a user is logged in. When a user is logged out the search works correctly, a search query for `d` will show results of every game with the character `d` in it.

Any help is gladly appreciated!

Thanks!

Below is my code.

**models.py**

```
class Game_Info(models.Model):
    id = models.IntegerField(primary_key=True, unique=True, blank=True, editable=False)
    game_title = models.CharField(max_length=100, null=True)
    game_rank = models.IntegerField(default=1)
    game_image = models.ImageField(default='default.png', upload_to='game_covers', null=True, blank=True)

class User_Info(models.Model):
    id = models.IntegerField(primary_key=True, blank=True)
    image = models.ImageField(default='/profile_pics/default.png', upload_to='profile_pics', null=True, blank=True)
    user = models.OneToOneField(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL,blank=True, null=True, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    rank = models.IntegerField(default=1)
```

**views.py**

```
def is_valid_queryparam(param):
    return param != '' and param is not None

def search_filter_view(request):
    user_profile_games_filter = Game_Info.objects.all()
    user_profile = User_Info.objects.all()
    title_query = request.POST.get('q')  

    if is_valid_queryparam(title_query):
        user_profile_games_filter = user_profile_games_filter.filter(game_title__icontains=title_query)

    if request.user.is_authenticated:
        user_profile = User_Info.objects.filter(user=request.user)
        user_profile_game_obj = User_Info.objects.get(user=request.user)
        user_profile_rank = int(user_profile_game_obj.rank)


        user_profile_games_filter = Game_Info.objects.annotate(
            user_unlocked_game=Case(
                When(game_rank__lte=user_profile_rank, then=Value(True)),
                default=Value(False),
                output_field=BooleanField()
            )
        )

        context = {
            'user_profile': user_profile,  
            'user_profile_games_filter': user_profile_games_filter,
            'title_query' : title_query
        }

    else:
        context = {
            'user_profile': user_profile,
            'user_profile_games_filter': user_profile_games_filter,
            'title_query' : title_query
       }

    return render(request, "search_results.html", context)
```

**search.html**

```
<h1>Results for &#34;{{ title_query }}&#34;</h1>


            {% for content in user_profile_games_filter %}
                {% if content.user_unlocked_game %}
                        <!-- unlocked games logic -->
                        <a class="game-tile-container" href="{% url 'detail' content.pk %}">
                            <li class="results_info">
                                <img src= "{{ content.game_image.url }}"> 
                                <span class="results_title">{{ content.game_title }}</span>
                            </li>
                        </a>
        
                        {% else %}
                        <!-- locked games logic -->
                        <a class="game-tile-container" href="{% url 'detail' content.pk %}">
                            <li class="results_info">
                                <div class="locked_game">
                                    <img class="lock-img" src={% static 'images/treasure-chest-closed-alt.png' %} />
                                    <img src= "{{ content.game_image.url }}"> 
                                    <button class="level-up">Reach level {{ content.game_rank }} to unlock</button>
                                </div>
                                <span class="results_title">{{ content.game_title }}</span>
            
                            </li>
                        </a>
                {% endif %}
            {% endfor %}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Issue:

```
user_profile_games_filter = Game_Info.objects.annotate(
            user_unlocked_game=Case(
                When(game_rank__lte=user_profile_rank, then=Value(True)),
                default=Value(False),
                output_field=BooleanField()
            )
        )
```

**SOLUTION** for anyone new; found after a long search and talk in the comments!:

Create a new variable where you store a list of the ID's of the filtered objects, in this case is the variable `user_profile_games_filter`:

```
NEW_VARIABLE = user_profile_games_filter.values_list('id', flat=True)
```

Next, with the filtered objects, assign it to the desired object, making sure that you filter the id using `id__in` and it should be equal to the list of IDs. No loop needed!

```
user_profile_games_filter = Game_Info.objects.filter(id__in=NEW_VARIABLE).annotate(...)
```

Comment: @jaymine If I remove that than the query works corretly but a game that should be unlocked is locked so I think I need that.

Comment: @spidey677 What happens if you add this line: user_profile_games_filter.annotate(...) instead of Game_Info.objects.annotate(...)?

Comment: I get the error ``'QuerySet' object has no attribute 'objects'``

Comment: What if you remove the .objects part: user_profile_games_filter.annotate(...) since you were able to use "user_profile_games_filter.filter" a few lines above.

Comment: the query works correctly but a game that should be unlocked is locked just like the suggestion before :/

Comment: Since it seems Game_Info collects all the objects instead of the wanted objects only, I'm not sure it will work though:   user_profile_games_filter = Game_Info.user_profile_games_filter.annotate()?

Comment: with that suggestion I get this error ``type object 'Game_Info' has no attribute 'user_profile_games_filter'`` :/

Comment: Oof okay, I just found something, how about get the ID's of all the objects you want in a new variable* like this: NEW_VARIABLE = user_profile_games_filter.values_list('id', flat=True). Then with the Game_Info line:  Game_Info.objects.filter(id=NEW_VARIABLE).annotate(...)

Comment: @with that suggestion I get ``The QuerySet value for an exact lookup must be limited to one result using slicing.``

Comment: I found somewhere where a solution for this is to add '__in', try adding that when you're assigning user_profile_games_filter, to id, like this: user_profile_games_filter = Game_Info.objects.filter(id__in=NEW_VARIABLE).annotate(...) I hope it works..

Comment: Hell yeah!!!! That works! You're a ninja! Happy Monday to you dude!

Comment: Finally!!! Guess I'll edit my post fr anyone wondering too.. Happy Money to you too!

Comment: I just accepted the answer and upvoted. thanks again!